# How to change number length format?

Tags: java

By the given task, the numbers can be 000, 001, 002 and so on.
How can I save this number format?

```
int i = 000;
i++; 
System.out.println(i);  //the output is 1 but I want 001
```

So how can I have the value of `i` like `001`?

Comment: `i = 000` is the same as `i = 0`. If you want to change how it outputs you can use `System.out.printf`

Comment: There is no **number** 001. Only the number 1, and maybe the *literal* 01 (which indicates octal). 001 only makes sense a **string**.

Comment: You can format it. `String.format()` would work, you could also store it as a string (though that might not be very useful). If you just need the format, String.format would work perfectly for only when you need it to be formatted.

Answer (score 0):

Store the original value in a String.

Try this: `String originalValue = "000";`

Comment: This might not fully align with OP's intention. For one, why bother storing a number in a string at all? OP wants to be able to manipulate the data as a number, while being able to format it to have beginning 0's. In that case, wouldn't `String.format` be a better approach?

Answer (score 0):

To display you int with a length of 3 digits, you can use `String.format` like this:

```
System.out.println(String.format("%03d", i));
```

Answer (score -1):

The language-independent name for what it sounds like you're trying to do is "format".
A lot of languages with C heritage will have a function named something like `printf`, `fprintf`, or `sprintf`, with a common protocol of `%` markers for their arguments.

[This looks like the Java version.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/numberformat.html)